# Does grouping numbers with parentheses in Ruby not work?

Tags: ruby, math

I was trying to write a small program in Ruby, and I ran into the following problem: Ruby doesn't seem to be able to group numbers in parentheses.

For example:

```
puts (2 - 0) / 10

# prints out 0
```

There is obviously a flaw in the logic here. What should be happening is that `(2 - 0)` gets evaluated first (according to the order of operations) and then `(2 - 0)` should get divided by `10`.

Does grouping with parentheses in Ruby not work? By the way, I'm using 2.1.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing integer division without realizing it. `2 / 10` does equal `0` in integer division.

Try instead running this:

```
puts (2 - 0) / 10.0

# prints out 0.2
```

You will probably get an answer more like what you're expecting. The reason is that by changing `10` to `10.0`, you coerce the operation into floating point division.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying. I guess I forgot that there is a difference between integer division and float division :P